# Is this a valid usage of @cached for autotracking of Ember Octane?

Tags: ember.js, ember-octane, glimmer.js

Recently I encountered an use case of `@cached` from [tracked-toolbox](https://github.com/pzuraq/tracked-toolbox) when writing a Glimmer component with autotracking. Here is an example code snippet:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

/**
 * Example usage
 * <PersonInfo
 *  @a={{this.objA}}
 *  @b={{this.stringB}}
 *  @c={{this.intC}}
 * />
 * Where objA can be a large object
 */

export default class PersonInfo extends Component {

  /**
   * I hope @cached here can help avoid re-running output getter in each
   * of the other getters, e.g. this.msg, this.link, this.name
   * But whenever any input args changes it triggers update 
   * (i.e. parent run this.objA = newObj)
   */
  get output() {
    return someExpensiveLogic(this.args.a, this.args.b, this.args.c);
  }

  get msg() {
    return translate(this.output.msg);
  }

  get link() {
    return convert(this.output.link);
  }

  get name() {
    return change(this.output.name);
  }
}
```

```
{{!-- In the template --}}
<div>
  {{this.name}}
  {{this.msg}}
  {{this.link}}
</div>
```

Without using `@cached`, the above code will execute the `output` getter 3 times when rendering, once for each of `msg`, `link` and `name`.

I also thought about building my own cache for `output`, but it requires me to manually keep track of which state is used and hash them, which could be expensive and hard to maintain.

From my understanding, what `@cached` provides is an access to the "global tag" in the auto tracking system, so I can rely on that tag to determine when the cache needs refresh.

Since this is not supported in a company project I work on for now, I hope this usage it can encourage us to add such support later.

Note: I found that `@cached` is convenient wrapper of

```js
import { createCache, getValue } from '@glimmer/tracking/primitives/cache';
```

So fundamentally what I need is `@glimmer/tracking/primitives/cache`.

Answer (score 2):

Posting a follow up here based on an offline discussion.

This is a valid usage of the `@cached` utility from [tracked-toolbox](https://github.com/pzuraq/tracked-toolbox#cached). The narrow use case meets the below requirements:

1. The `output` getter is expensive.
2. The result of `output` is used multiple times in other getters in JS. (If `this.output` is only used directly in the template, it will already have exactly the same semantics around rerunning as it does with `@cache`.)
3. Compared to an explicit cache of the *values* used in the `output` getter, using `@cache` will not evaluate changes of the arguments' values, which means if `this.args.b` is set to the same value as before, the `output` getter will still rerun. This is not a concern in this use case, because I know the parent will not set the same value in input args.